# Universal Donsker classes and bounded variation

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, bounded-variation, empirical-processes

I just read in a paper [A Donsker Theorem for Lévy Measures](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0590) the following statement

> $BV$-balls are universal Donsker classes (page 7, Examples 3.2 - Compound Poisson Processes)

$BV$ stands here for bounded variation.
Unfortunately there is no reference for this result. I was wondering, is this some sort of trivial? Does anyone know a reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reference for this statement, by Donsker himself published in

[*Dudley,R.M. (1992) "Frechet Differentiability,  p-Variation  and Uniform  Donsker Classes", "The Annals of Probability" (p. 1971)*](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176989537)

**Theorem** (Bounded Variation and universal $P-$Donsker classes):

For any (bounded and unbounded) interval $J\subseteq \mathbb R$, any $p$ with $0<p<2$ and any $M<\infty$, the set of functions $\mathcal{F}_{p,M}$ defined as

$$
 \mathcal{F}_{p,M}:=\{f:\,J\to\mathbb R, v(f,p)\leq M\}
$$

with

$$
 v(f,p):=v(f,p,J):=\sup\{\sum_{i=1}^n \lvert f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})\rvert^p:x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_n\in J,n\in\mathbb N \}
$$
is a uniform $P-$Donsker class.

If we choose $p=1$, we have exactly the total variation statement.

**For reference,**  in the specific case of the question this then reduces to show that the functions in the class
$$
\mathcal G_{\varphi}:=\Big\{\mathcal F^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\varphi(-\bullet)}\right] \ast 1_{(-\infty,t]}:\;\lvert t\rvert\geq\zeta>0\Big\}
$$

are of bounded variation, which is true, since in the setting of the question the operator $\mathcal F^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\varphi(-\bullet)}\right]$ (in the paper called deconvolution operator) is a finite signed measure.